# Setting attribute of type owner on microsoft CRM from java

Tags: java, web-services, crm

Does anyone know the equivalent code in Java to fill in an attribute of the type owner?

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.type = EntityName.systemuser.ToString();
owner.Value = user.UserId;
```

I've used an entityreference to owner and solved the problem of empty Guid. but now I'm hitting:

```
[ERROR] Invalid ownerIdType = 7
```

I think that is related to owneridtype attribute that in the above C# is the second line, m current code is the following:

```
OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType owneridtype = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
owneridtype.setKey("owneridtype");
OrganizationServiceStub.OptionSetValue owner2 = new OrganizationServiceStub.OptionSetValue();
owner2.setValue(Integer.parseInt("8"));
owneridtype.setValue(owner2);  
collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(owneridtype);  

OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType vendedor = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
vendedor.setKey("ownerid");
OrganizationServiceStub.Guid vendedorGuid = utils.readVendCrm(serviceStub,args[17]);
OrganizationServiceStub.EntityReference owner = new OrganizationServiceStub.EntityReference();
owner.setLogicalName("owner");
owner.setId(vendedorGuid);
vendedor.setValue(owner);
collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(vendedor);
```

Comment: Java, it's an external application using the soap web service, not a solution inside CRM

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about Java and CRM 2011 I'm afraid but this article may be useful.

[Write Java and other Non-.NET Client Applications for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx).

Also related questions:

- [Connect MS Dynamics CRM 2011 from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014275/connect-ms-dynamics-crm-2011-from-java)
- [Connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-premise web service with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115865/connecting-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-web-service-with-java)

Comment: Thx, the first document it was the one i've followed to jump start the development of the interface. It's good because it helps on how to connect and consume the webservice. It lacks detailed information in all the classes that are generated from the wsdl2java, and that is the problem i'm having in converting C# example codes to JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

The correct entity that it should be referenced is systemuser not owner, that was my error.
The correct code is:

```
    OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType vendedor = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
   vendedor.setKey("ownerid");
   OrganizationServiceStub.Guid vendedorGuid = utils.readVendCrm(serviceStub,args[17]);
   OrganizationServiceStub.EntityReference owner = new OrganizationServiceStub.EntityReference();
   owner.setLogicalName("systemuser");
   owner.setId(vendedorGuid);
   vendedor.setValue(owner);
   collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(vendedor);
```